# Understanding PPStream

Tags: javascript

It's http://kan.pps.tv/web/pps.js

`PPStream.prototype.pps_width="400px";`

The PPStream is never declared, is this PPStream object purely generated by 'prototype' way? I know how 'prototype property' works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PPStream` *is* actually declared. It's declared as a function, though, not as a regular variable:

```
function PPStream (id) {

    var self = this;    

    this.reset = function (pid) 
    {
```

See [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects) on the Mozilla Developer Network (especially [this bit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_Properties_for_an_Object_Type) on  `prototype`) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

It is declared: `function PPStream (id) {`

It is just done so using a function declaration instead of a function expression, so it doesn't take place in top-down order.